# Don't show the delete button in tools > flags if I can't cast a vote on a post

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I was in the 10k-tools section on Meta, and there was a "not an answer" flag, but next to the button to flag or decline it, there was a button to delete the answer.  While I have the ability to delete answers, I don't really unless they have some downvotes on them.  Sure enough I clicked on the delete button and got a message telling me I couldn't delete that message.

[image: Delete Button in Review Queue]

[image: Can't delete messagebox]

This can also happen if you've already cast a delete vote on something that shows up on the flag page (ie: the button is still shown even though you've cast a delete vote already).

[image]

How about not showing me the delete button for an answer in the mod tools if I can't actually cast a vote against that post?

Comment: That's not review, 10K tools are a whole different beast. :)

Comment: Worth to mention in this context, that you can cast actual delete vote on answer with  score of 0 (maybe even positive score) from within the low quality review queue. NAA is not VLQ though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, there is no flag queue in review, there is only the flag review queue in the 10-k tools, not sure how that's a different beast, since it's the only one.

Comment: It's not review, it's not even recorded anywhere. It is just a place where 10K users help the actual moderators with real flags.

Comment: Yes, it's a shadow (subset) of the queue that the mods work out of, but it's for reviewing flags.  Not sure what else you'd call it.

Comment: It's just "moderator queue" as far as I know... "review" is used to describe anything under http://stackoverflow.com/review, note the 10K tools use different URL: http://stackoverflow.com/tools where the flags queue is one of the tools.

Comment: @Flyk hide and disable are two different things, your edit feels bit too radical

Comment: Hide would be the same method that is used for the flag button if you're already flagged - no harm in keeping it consistent, no?